# what standard defines the contents of faces-config.xml? - Looking for doc in all the wrong places

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2

Is this part of the JSF 2 spec and I should be able to find the documentation here: https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/2.2/index.html?

Is it container specific and I should be able to find it here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ ?

I've spent a lot of time clicking through these sites looking for this. Mostly I search the interwebs hoping to find a post with an example with what I need.

In short, is there comprehensive documentation of what is allowed to be in this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

faces-config.xml is part of the framework (ie. not container specific). You can find the xml definition file from http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd which contains all the available tags, including some documentation for them. The xsd is specially helpful with IDE:s, but is most likely not the kind of documentation you were looking for.

I have not found one definitive "taglib" documentation about the faces-config.xml, but there are a lot of nice examples and tutorials which contain most of the use case. One example is [Oracles JavaEE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-configure002.htm#BNAWP)